# ブラウザの多重クリック防止

Tags: html, html5

CGIを使って、Webサーバー内のコマンドを実行したいのですが、クライアント側での多重クリックを防ぐためWebブラウザ上でボタンクリック後、一定期間ボタンを無効にするようなことは出来るでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

可能です。
ボタンクリック直後にボタンを無効にした後、setTimeout等で一定時間経過後にボタンの無効を解除するとよいと思います。

Answer (score 3):

Cookieか何かに現在時刻を保存して比較するか、
ボタンを無効化して押せなくするか(念のためフラグも入れとくといいです)
色々やり方はあるかと思います。
サーバ側でセッション管理するかすればクライアントではなく
サーバで弾くことも出来るかと思います。

```js
var lastClick=0;
var interval=10*1000;
function click1(e){
    var now = (+new Date());
    var diff = now - lastClick;
    if(interval<=diff){
        lastClick=now;
        //This Allow
        console.log("On Clicked 1 : "+(new Date(now)));
        return;
    }
    //This Deny
}

var isLock=false;
function click2(e){
    if(!isLock){
        isLock=true;
        $(e).attr("disabled","disabled");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(e).removeAttr("disabled");
            isLock=false;
        },interval);
        console.log("On Clicked 2 : "+(new Date()));
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="click1();">秒数管理</button>
<button onclick="click2(this);">ボタン無効化</button>
```